# Batch file to delete the .txt files inside the folder

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for a batch file script to delete `.txt` files inside the folder structure. For example, my folder structure would be `202303`. Every month, we have folders like `202304,202305` and so on.
Inside this folder, we have subfolders like `20230301,20230302`, and so on. Every day one subfolder is created by date ex 20230405. The .txt files are located inside this folder, and we need to delete them through a batch file.

I created a batch script to delete the .txt file, but it won't change dynamically daily based on the date.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

 CD /D E:\202304\20230404\

 
    for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  
DEL %%f

    )
```

Comment: What's wrong with `del /s "E:\202304\*.txt"` (without the `for`)?

Comment: But I want to go to the subfolder by getting the date and looking for .txt to delete.

Comment: Also, how the script can change the folders if it goes to the next month file ex: 202305

Comment: `for /d %%a in (E:\2023*) do del /s "%%a\*.txt"` should do. USE WITH CARE!

Comment: It is not working for me. Not sure whether I have tried the script properly. Not getting any errors.

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /d %%a in (E:\2023*) do del /s "%%a\*.txt"

Comment: Try `.... do del /s "%%~fa\*.txt` See `for /?` for what the `~f` modifer does.